# Using OpenGL extensions conditionally

Tags: c++, c, opengl-es, opengl-es-1.1

I'm a bit confused about how to use OpenGL extensions (specifically VBOs and draw_texture). I know you can check for them in the GL_EXTENSIONS string, but then what? If the extensions are available can I just call the relevant functions as needed or do I have to load them eg using GLEW? And if they aren't available is it OK to have those functions in my code as long as I don't call them, or will that cause unresolved symbol errors in the run-time linker in case the extensions aren't available?

And is it the same across multiple platforms, ie Linux, Windows, Android (native), Mac and iOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If the extensions are available can I just call the relevant functions as needed

No.

> or do I have to load them eg using GLEW?

Yes. You can do it manually as well.

> And if they aren't available is it OK to have those functions in my code as long as I don't call them,

Yes.

> or will that cause unresolved symbol errors in the run-time linker in case the extensions aren't available?

Since extensions are loaded dynamically at runtime, the executable linker doesn't care about them. All it sees are some variables named `__glew_gl…` or similar, which are redefined in the header to `gl…` and the linker doesn't care what value they have.

The extension loader can set them either to a null pointer if not available, or to a stub function that emits a warning message, error condition or similar.

If the extension is available, then the extension loader sets those function pointer variables to point to the actual functions.